# CARLA simulator blinked when trained to 30 epochs

Tags: python, simulation, reinforcement-learning, carla

I am using CARLA to simulate autonomous drving vehicle. And I use CARLA Python API to do data communication. But I encountered CARLA flash back when epoch reaches 30. Here is the error information:

```
(base) srt_lzy@qh802-X299-WU8:~/Carla$ ./CarlaUE4.sh 
4.26.2-0+++UE4+Release-4.26 522 0
Disabling core dumps.
Signal 11 caught.
Malloc Size=65538 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=65554 
CommonUnixCrashHandler: Signal=11
Malloc Size=131160 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=196744 
Malloc Size=131160 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=327928 
Engine crash handling finished; re-raising signal 11 for the default handler. Good bye.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't know how to solve it. One post i see on the internet said, it means the swap space of my computer is not enough. Is it true? I also see that swap space can rarely be not enough. Here is my computer information:

```
(base) srt_lzy@qh802-X299-WU8:~/project/scenario_generation$ free -h
              total         used        free      shared    buffer    available
Internal Memory：        62Gi       3.8Gi        48Gi       124Mi        10Gi        57Gi
Swap：       2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```